# RoR ActiveRecord/ActiveRelation error: undefined method + for nilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm honestly more lost than I have ever been programming ever. Recently, I've been attempting to move away from 5+ years of PHP development and try Ruby/Rails. I picked up Agile Web Development with Rails and I've been following along with it. Versions I carry that differ include Mac OS X Snow Leopard (originally, having migrated to Mountain Lion) and Ruby/Rails 1.8.7/3.2.6.

When adding quantity to the cart, my code appears as so:
cart.rb (model)

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy

  def add_product(product_id)
    current_item = line_items.find_by_product_id(product_id)
    if current_item
      current_item.quantity += 1
    else
      current_item = line_items.build(:product_id => product_id)
    end
    current_item
  end
end
```

I have attr_accessible :quantity within the line_item.rb model and within line_items_controller.rb I'm calling @line_item = current_cart.add_product(product.id). The code is perfectly function the first time you add a product to the cart, yet the second time Rails gives me the error:

```
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

and points to the obvious line in questions (above with the plus). Any suggestions? Thanks.

EDIT: If anyone can also recommend in the comments if this is the best route to learning Rails, or if I should pick up another book or use another website/etc., because this isn't the first time that code has been wrong in this book.

EDIT 2: Excerpted line_items_controller.rb (lines 40-56)

```
def create
  @cart = current_cart
  product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @line_items = @cart.add_product(product.id) #product.id, product didn't work.

  respond_to do |format|
    if @line_item.save
      format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart, :notice => 'Line item was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :json => @line_item, :status => :created, :location => @line_item }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.json { render :json => @line_item.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Also, since the code works for one item but not sequential additions of the same item, I don't think it has to do with .save.

Comment: While I haven't read AWDR, coming from a very similar background I found Michael Hartl's [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) to be a good resource to get up to speed with Rails quickly.  It's the most up-to-date tutorial resource I've found, gives a wonderful introduction to the entire Rails ecosystem including testing and deployment, and is not too simplistic to be boring for someone with significant programming experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you make sure quantity is not nil.

try

```
if current_item && current_item.quantity.present?
```

instead of

```
if current_item
```

Comment: You're right. For whatever reason, my DB migration failed to set the default value to 1.

Comment: while this prevents an exception from being raised, the overall behaviour is probably not as desired - sounds like you'd end up with two line items with the same product_id, but with some of the quantities being nil

Comment: I've deleted my line_items from the db, rolled back the migration which added the quantity and reapplied it with a default value of 1.

Answer (score 2):

Never use `attr_accessor` (not to be confused with `attr_accessible`) with an attribute that is backed by a database column: you're replacing the active record generated accessor (which would have returned the column value, which presumably has a default of 1) with one that uses an instance variable. That instance variable isn't set, so nil is returned

The earlier editions of Agile Web Development with Rails were fine (I used to have the first edition) but I would make sure you have a recent edition - I think they're up to 4th or 5th now.

Comment: Thanks. I only added that assuming it may have been an error. Although attr_accessor was added for cart_id and product_id when I generated the model. Should I take that back out?

Comment: are you sure it was attr_accessor and not attr_accessible ?

Answer (score 0):

What the error is saying is that your `current_item` object is `nil`. Your `find_by_product_id` query did not found any object with the id you passed as a parameter.
Try checking the ids passed by the controller to your model.

Comment: Webrick says that the query itself is fine.